# What is a good way to load images in Android WebView?

Tags: android, html, image, webview

Premise

1. My WebView have many images，Like news app.
2. WebView build by Stitching body from server with my local html template.
3. If i wait webView when it `onProgressChanged()` `newProgress == 100`,then show it for user, it will wait lots of time, and when network is not good, this experience was to terrible
4. So, i want know if has  a good way to load images ?

Two way i know

1. Image not display immediately, and when i slide the page image start cache and display
2. Or another way, just display text and image display placeholder with local for user, and i start a Thread to cache images on backGround, when images cache finish to replace placeholder

What is a good way to load images in Android WebView ?

Please Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

One of the most famous way to load images from any source into the app is by using an image loading library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Follow the setup steps to get started. In the activity that you want an image to be loaded, declare an ImageView variable and use

```
ImageView imej = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageID);
Glide.with(this).load("URL").into(imej);
```

If you wish to use the cache capabilities, add

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE*)
```

between the .load() and .into() methods. Note that DiskCacheStrategy has 4 types. Choose wisely.